# Get data per Mon - Sunday week

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with columns(id, name, total, timestamp) column. I wish to obtain data for total per week, per candidate with postgreSQL.

For example

```
Date, total, name (columns)

Jan 16-23, 23 , Marcus

Jan 16-23, 21 , Dennis

Jan 16-23, 18 , Sydney

Jan 23-39, 14, Marcus

Jan 23-39, 13, Dennis

Jan 23-39, 12, Sydney

Jan 30- Feb 5, 10, Marcus

Jan 30- Feb 5, 14, Dennis

Jan 30- Feb 5, 21, Sydney
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**.  Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.